# Reducer values in MapReduce need to be copied, otherwise subject to modification?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In a MapReduce application, I have this arbitrary WritableComparable implementation called AnonymousPair and I have noticed this

```
import com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue;

public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, AnonymousPair, LongWritable, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<AnonymousPair> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
        // ...
        MinMaxPriorityQueue<AnonymousPair> pQueue = MinMaxPriorityQueue
                .orderedBy(new AnonymousPair().comparator())
                .maximumSize(Constants.MaxKeywords)
                .create();

        for(AnonymousPair val : values) {
            pQueue.add(new AnonymousPair(val)); // No problem with copy constructor
            // pQueue.add(val);                 // Wrong! Every element in pQueue will be the same 
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't use 'copy constructor', every element in the pQueue ends up being the same. Could anyone help me understand this? Thanks!
My guesses are

1. Reference to Reducer Values elements subject to modification. It is somewhere in the doc but I missed it.
2. I'm using Google Guava MinMaxPriorityQueue wrongly
3. Or something wrong with my WritableComparable implementation

My AnonymousPair implementation

```
    public static class AnonymousPair implements WritableComparable<AnonymousPair> {
        private String a = "";
        private Float b = 0f;
        public AnonymousPair() {}
        public AnonymousPair(String a, Float b) {this.a = a; this.b = b;}
        public AnonymousPair(AnonymousPair o) {this.a = o.a; this.b = o.b;}

        public Comparator<AnonymousPair> comparator() {return new AnonymousPairComparator();}

        class AnonymousPairComparator implements Comparator<AnonymousPair> {
            @Override
            public int compare(AnonymousPair o1, AnonymousPair o2) {
                Float diff = o1.b - o2.b;
                if(diff == 0) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if(diff < 0) {
                    return 1;   // Reverse order
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(AnonymousPair o) {
            int temp = this.a.compareTo(o.a);
            if(temp == 0) {
                return -this.b.compareTo(o.b);
            } else {
                return temp;
            }
        }

        // More overriding...
    }
```

Comment: Show your `AnonymousPair` class and where `pQueue` is implemented/defined

Comment: I don't see where your `ret` variable is declared.

Comment: Sorry. It should just be 'return'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html#reduce(K2,%20java.util.Iterator,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter)):

> The framework will reuse the key and value objects that are passed
>   into the reduce, therefore the application should clone the objects
>   they want to keep a copy of. In many cases, all values are combined
>   into zero or one value.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for. But how does reuse help the framework? WritableComparable seems lightweight to me for it only keeps a few reference.

Comment: Yeah but combine that with processing of very large files where you can have billions of rows you can end up with thousands if not millions of values being processed per key per reduce call.